# How to check if ETH transaction was ever sent

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, hash

I'm creating a transaction with web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction. I'm then storing that transaction hash, then sending it over the ETH network with web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction

How do I programmatically check if a signed transaction was or wasn't sent yet over the network yet? I'm not interested if it was mined, confirmed or rejected - I just want to check if it was ever sent or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "sent"? Sent to one node? To two nodes? To 50% of the Ethereum network? To 100%?

Comment: Generally, txs are propagated pretty quickly between nodes.